# Strange special character handling in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, character-encoding, special-characters

I have added a java class file with encoding "ISO-8859-1" to an existing project:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String var = "è";
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}
```

[image]

after running the console shows:

> ?

I expected to see

> è

in the console.

[image]

To find out the error I created a complete new Project and added a new class with encoding "ISO-8859-1" and the console returns:

> è

[image]

My settings about encoding is also the same in both projects:

[image]

Where to set the correct encoding so my existing project returns the correct character?

Comment: Try setting project encoding to the the same as the file encoding. But the better approach would be to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: As mentoined. The Settings are the same in both projects. The screenshot looks the same for both projects.

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached so that we can reproduce and fix it.

Comment: It must be something with compiler? When converting the class to kotlin, then the console shows that special french character.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be appreciated. Thank you!