# Intellij converting special characters to different characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, character-encoding

I am trying to deal with special characters but Intellij converting special characters to different characters. I have already updated my default encoding to UTF-8 standard but still facing issues.

[image]

While printing the same data to the IntelliJ console it's converting the same data to a different format. please find the below examples.

Examples:

"**Avstånd**" is converted to ==> **Avst├Ñnd**

"**välein**" is converted to ==> **v├ñlein**

I have already checked the JSON file. It's showing me Encoding the UTF-8 standard. I also tried the below links but still no luck yet.

1. https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/766
2. [Strange special character handling in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096306/strange-special-character-handling-in-intellij)
3. [IntelliJ IDEA Terminal Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398429/intellij-idea-terminal-special-characters)
4. [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Comment: `while retrieving the data it's converted the same data to different charset.` add more details here. Where and how do you retrieve it? Why do you think it is an IDE that converts it? If you open it in another editor, what do you see?

Comment: @Andrey: I have updated the information.

Answer (score 1):

Encode you file (only where you have harcoded strings whit special characters) as ISO-8859-1

Comment: It works for me with latin accents